# How do i write csv basis on comparing two csv file[column based]

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files:

csv1
csv2

(*note headers can be differ)

csv1 has 1 single column an csv2 has 5 columns

now column 1 of csv1 has some matching values in column2 of csv2

my concern is how can i write a csv where column1 of csv1 does not have a MATCHING VALUES to column2 of csv2

I have attached three files csv1, csv2 and expected output..

Expected Output:

```
ProfileID,id,name,class ,rollnumber
1,lkha,prince,sfasd,DAS
2,hgfhfk,kabir,AD,AD
5,jlh,antriskh,ASDA,AD
```

CSV 1:

```
id,name
10927,prince
109582,kabir
f546416,rahul
g44674,saini
r7341,antriskh
```

CSV 2:

```
ProfileID,id,name,class ,rollnumber
1,lkha,prince,sfasd,DAS
2,hgfhfk,kabir,AD,AD
3,f546416,rahul,AD,FF
44,g44674,saini,DD,FF
5,jlh,antriskh,ASDA,AD
```

I tried using converting them into dictionary and match them csv1 keys to csv2 values but it is not working as expected

```
def read_csv1(filename):
    prj_structure = {}
    f = open(filename, "r")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    lst = data.split("\n")
    prj = ""
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        val = lst[i].split(",")
        if len(val)>0:
            prj = val[0]
        if prj!="":
            if prj not in prj_structure.keys():
                prj_structure[prj] = []
             prj_structure[prj].append([val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4])
    return prj_structure


def read_csv2(filename):
    prj_structure = {}
    f = open(filename, "r")
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    lst = data.split("\n")
    prj = ""
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        val = lst[i].split(",")
        if len(val)>0:
            prj = val[0]
        if prj!="":
            if prj not in prj_structure.keys():
                prj_structure[prj] = []
             prj_structure[prj].append([val[0])
    return prj_structure


csv1_data = read_csv1("csv1.csv")
csv2_data = read_csv2("csv2.csv")

for k, v in csv1_data.items():
    for ks, vs in csv2_data.items():
        if k==vs[0][0]:
            #here it is not working
            sublist = []
            sublist.append(k)
```

Comment: You should use the [builtin python `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead of writing your own parser.

Comment: Nothing worked,that'a why i moved to different code. But it is also not giving result...can you tell me how to do it

Comment: ok, can you explain why the `rahul` and `saini` rows were filtered out? They appear in both csv_1 and csv_2.

Comment: yes only those rows which are not included in both csv. I am checking you answer and others answer

Comment: Which columns between the csvs have to match? `name`?

Comment: Csv 1 column name id ,csv 2 column name id

Comment: Ok, i changed my post to that logic. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DictReader from the csv package.

```
import csv

f1 = open('csv1.csv')
csv_1 = csv.DictReader(f1)
f2 = open('csv2.csv')
csv_2 = csv.DictReader(f2)


first_dict = {}

for row in csv_1:
    first_dict[row['name']]=row

f1.close()

f_out = open('output.csv','w')
csv_out = csv.DictWriter(f_out,csv_2.fieldnames)
csv_out.writeheader()

for second_row in csv_2:
    if second_row['name'] in first_dict:
        first_row = first_dict[second_row['name']]
        if first_row['id']!=second_row['id']:
            csv_out.writerow(second_row)

f2.close()
f_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of csv processing, using the builtin [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module makes most of the error prone processing trivial. Given your example values, the following code should produce the desired results. I use  [comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) to do the filtering.

```py
import csv
import io

# example data, as StringIO that will behave like file objects
raw_csv_1 = io.StringIO('''\
id,name
10927,prince
109582,kabir
f546416,rahul
g44674,saini
r7341,antriskh''')

raw_csv_2 = io.StringIO('''\
ProfileID,id,name,class,rollnumber
1,lkha,prince,sfasd,DAS
2,hgfhfk,kabir,AD,AD
3,f546416,rahul,AD,FF
44,g44674,saini,DD,FF
5,jlh,antriskh,ASDA,AD''')

# in your actual data, you would use actual file objects instead, like
# with open('location/of/your/csv_1') as file_1:
#     raw_csv_1 = file_1.read()
# with open('location/of/your/csv_2') as file_2:
#     raw_csv_2 = file_2.read()
```

Then we need to transform then into `csv.reader` objects:

```py
csv_1 = csv.reader(raw_csv_1)
next(csv_1)  # consume once to skip the header

csv_2 = csv.reader(raw_csv_2)
header = next(csv_2)  # consume once to skip the header, but store it
```

Last but not least, collect the names of the first csv in a set to use them as lookup table, filter the second csv with it, and write it back as `'result.csv'` into your file system.

```py
skip_keys = {id_ for id_, name in vals_1}
result = [row for row in vals_2 if row[1] not in skip_keys]

# at this point, result contains
# [['1', 'lkha', 'prince', 'sfasd', 'DAS'], 
#  ['2', 'hgfhfk', 'kabir', 'AD', 'AD'],
#  ['5', 'jlh', 'antriskh', 'ASDA', 'AD']]

with open('result.csv', 'w') as result_file:
    csv.writer(result_file).writerows(header+result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option, I have always found pandas as a great tool to import and manipulate CSV files.

```
import pandas as pd
# Read in both the CSV files
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('csv1.csv'))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('csv2.csv'))

# Iterate over both DataFrames and if any id's from in df_2 match
# df_1, remove them from df_2
for num1, row1 in df_1.iterrows():
    for num2, row2 in df_2.iterrows():
        if row1['id'] == row2['id']:
            df_2.drop(num2, inplace=True)

df_2.head()
```